# Azure Data Factory - Excluding folder within a container when using storage events triggers

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm currently trying to find a solution to our trigger happy ADF triggers.  I have taken over a Databricks / Delta lake ETL solution built on top of a Gen 2 data lake which uses ADF for orchestration.

The current setup uses the RAW > STAGE > BASE > ENRICHED data flow.  When a file lands in any RAW folders in any of the containers, a pipeline is triggered that calls a Databricks notebook which automatically converts TXT/CSV/XLSX/JSON files into a delta table.  This process is working as expected and saves us a considerable amount of time.  The issue is that I don't want this trigger to fire off against every storage event.

Obviously I could be more prescriptive with the trigger but my concern is that there will be various processes that could potentially stop working in the process.  So, I decided to see if there was a way in which to exclude specific folders within containers.

I have referred to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger?tabs=data-factory#json-schema), but I can only see ways to include locations not exclude them.

[image]

Does anyone know if this is possible?  If not I will have to look at a creating way more triggers than I want to cover all of our containers (25+).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As of now, **there is no option to exclude folders or containers.**

You can try this approach:

Keep all the needed folders with same naming convention .

**For example:** trigger_Folder1, trigger_Folder2 etc.
and in the storage event trigger , inside `Blob path begins with` option , provide value as '**trigger_**'